# Node.js HLTV scorebot not working

Tags: node.js, sockets

I can't get around with Node.js hltv scorebot(https://github.com/Nols1000/hltv-scorebot) but when I connect to hltv server with match id I don't get any logs about match. it just does some logs that don't worth anything and nothing more, has anyone grabbed match live data from hltv, are there another ways for doing this, except this api.
Here is my code

```
var Scorebot = require('hltv-scorebot');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
var client = io.sockets;


client.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log("connected");
    var match_id = socket.request._query['matchid'];
    console.log("match_id is " + match_id);
    var sb = new Scorebot();
    sb.connect('http://scorebot.hltv.org',10022,478323);

    sb.on('kill', function(killer, victim, weapon, headshot, assister) {
        console.log("kill event");
        console.log(killer, victim, weapon, headshot, assister);
        var killerName = killer.name;

        // Checking if assister exists
        if(assister)
            killerName = killer.name + " and " + assister.name;

        console.log(killer.name, 'killed', vicitim.name, 'with', weapon, headshot ? 'headshot' : '');
    });

    sb.on("time", function(time){
        /*console.log("time event fired");
        console.log(time);*/
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"time", args: arguments})
    });

    sb.on("player", function(playermanager){
        console.log("player");
        for (var i in playermanager){
            console.log(i);
            for (var j in playermanager[i]){
                console.log(j);
                console.log(playermanager[i]);
            }
        }
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"player", args: arguments})
    });

    sb.on("assist", function(assister, victim){
        /*console.log("assist");
        console.log(assister, victim);*/
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"assist", args: arguments})
    });

    sb.on("roundend", function(winner, tscore, ctscore){
        /*console.log("roundend");
        console.log(winner, tscore, ctscore);*/
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"roundend", args: arguments})
    });

    sb.on("playerjoin", function(player){
        /*console.log("playerjoin");
        console.log(player);*/
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"playerjoin", args: arguments})
    });

    socket.on("ttt", function(){process.exit(1)});

    sb.on("playerquit", function(player){
        /*console.log("playerquit");
        console.log(player);*/
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"playerquit", args: arguments})
    });


    sb.on('bombPlanted', function(bia) {
        /*console.log("bombPlanted");
        console.log(bia);*/
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"bombPlanted", args: arguments})
    });

    sb.on("roundstart", function(){
        /*console.log("Round started");*/
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"rountstart", args: arguments})
    });

    sb.on('score', function(score) {
        /*console.log("score");
        console.log(score);*/
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"score", args: arguments})
    });

    sb.on('mapchange', function(map) {
        socket.emit("msg", {type:"mapChange", args: arguments})
        /*console.log("map");
        console.log(map);*/
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HLTV has made many changes to their scorebot since the last update of the `hltv-scorebot` module. I've created a fork (available at https://github.com/andrewda/hltv-livescore) which is up-to-date with recent changes to HLTV.

Your code would look very similar as the core API of `hltv-scorebot` and `hltv-livescore` are almost identical. Here's a basic example of how you'd begin using it:

```
const Livescore = require('hltv-livescore');
const live = new Livescore({ listid: 478323 });

live.on('kill', (data) => {
    console.log('kill event');
    console.log(data.killer.name, 'killed', data.victim.name, 'with', data.weapon, data.headshot ? '(headshot)' : '');
});
```